# java instrumenting code

Tags: java, jvm, instrumentation

I have only user specific experience in using instrumenting (some mocking with powermock, some profiling in visualvm, chronon recording server).

In many cases when I used instrumenting on jvm that worked some time there was a jvm crash. When I instrumented jvm just after its startup frequency of crashes was much less. I think there are some problems with existing class instances, with call stack, etc. (however that is just my imho).
That is why I feel that instrumentation is so unreliable :(.

So are there any general rules when instrumentation should run? Or probably I am doing something wrong and there are magic jvm cmd params that saves it from crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible reasons

1. insufficient memory (maybe in adding the agent you omitted previous settings)
2. you have some classes which are obfuscated and cause BCI libraries to fail leading to a cascade of other issues
3. JNI native code libraries

if your jvm crashes are more pronounced when using a profiler then it looks more like a memory setting...check what happens to your heap settings when you alter your script for the agent...maybe add more more heap